# Calling takePicture inside AutoFocusCallback causes Error 100

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, autofocus

I have run into what I think is a device specific issue, but I wanted to see if anyone else has seen this behavior before. Below is the code I am using to capture a JPEG in my camera activity:

```
surfaceView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                if(success)
                {                           
                    Log.d(TAG, "Focusing...successful.");
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, null, jpegCallback);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Focusing...failed.");
                }

            }

        });
    }
});
```

This code works perfectly on my Nexus 4, but this afternoon I tried it on a Samsung Galaxy S3, and the camera server crashes with the following error messages:

```
Focusing...successful.
Camera server died!
ICamera died
Error 100
```

As you can see from the LogCat, the failure occurs when `camera.takePicture(...)` is called (i.e., the `jpegCallback` is never invoked). Later I got a friend with a Samsung Galaxy Note to try it, and it works fine on their phone.

Should I not be taking a picture from inside the auto focus callback? This seems like the appropriate place to put it. Any insight here would be awesome!

Comment: Do you have the autofocus permission set up in the manifest?

Comment: Yes. Permissions are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out a while back, and wanted to let others know how to fix this. What caused the crash was setting the preview size larger than the screen size of the device. This is why the Samsung Galaxy S3 would crash, but not the Nexus 4. Below is the relevant code I changed:

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> previewSizes, int width, int height) {
                double targetAspect = (double)width / (double)height;

        ArrayList<Camera.Size> matchedPreviewSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>();
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        for(Size previewSize : previewSizes) {
                double previewAspect = (double)previewSize.width / (double)previewSize.height;

                // Original broken code.
                //if(Math.abs(targetAspect - previewAspect) < ASPECT_TOLERANCE) {
                //        matchedPreviewSizes.add(previewSize);
                //}

                // Working code.
                if(Math.abs(targetAspect - previewAspect) < ASPECT_TOLERANCE &&
                            previewSize.width <= width && previewSize.height <= height) {
                        matchedPreviewSizes.add(previewSize);
                }
        }

        Camera.Size bestPreviewSize;
        if(!matchedPreviewSizes.isEmpty()) {
                bestPreviewSize = Collections.max(matchedPreviewSizes, sizeComparator);
        } else {
                bestPreviewSize = Collections.max(previewSizes, sizeComparator);
        }

        return bestPreviewSize;
}

private Comparator<Camera.Size> sizeComparator = new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        long lhsArea = lhs.height*lhs.width;
        long rhsArea = rhs.height*rhs.width;

        if(lhsArea > rhsArea) {
            return 1;
        } else if(lhsArea < rhsArea) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

};
```

In the above code, I show the original broken code along with the working code that caused my function to respect the maximum screen size of the device. Doing this fixed the crashes that were occurring on various devices.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello! I would like to send you an email regarding a freelance opportunity. Drop me a message on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/karlphillip) or [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/in/karlphillip) if you are interested.

Comment: Hey Karl! I sent a tweet your way with my contact info :)

Comment: I really can't see why your changes made the difference. Also if you are right about the cause of the problem why do you return  max Size if the matchedPreviewSizes is empty?

Comment: @user65721 Ha! You are right, it didn't do anything. I accidentally posted the working code originally. I've corrected the answer to show the broken code along with the working code. I mainly returned the max size as that's what the Android samples show; however, the more Android I do, the more bugs I find in their samples :)

Comment: thanks for fixing it. tell me about bugs of android samples, it is almost impossible to rely on their samples. Also it is worse when it comes to hardware related projects like camera apps. Btw for camera related code, this project is better source than android samples. https://github.com/lightbox/QuickSnap

Comment: can you please tell me what is sizeComparator? Thanks

Comment: @lukas It's just a simple Comparator object that sorts Camera.Size objects by their area. I have edited the answer to include its definition for your convenience.